# Cant attached printed pdf document as email attachment in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, printform

I am able to create a pdf document and I can browse the folder and open the document with no issue. But when my code try to attach the file as an attachment then it fails with this error, but the path and filename is correct. I suspect the file is somehow open which prevents the attachment.

Proof of files:

[image]

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
> Could not find file 'C:\TEMP\1104280343081_INV0950.pdf'.
> This part works perfectly

```
        Dim txtVarFile As String
        Dim txtVarEmail As String = "test@test.com"
        Dim txtVarPasss As String = "password"
        Dim txtVarSMTP As String = "smtp.gmail.com"
        Dim intVarPort As Integer = 587
        Dim txtVarDescription As String

        'Create Invoice and Save as pdf document
        txtVarFile = "C:\TEMP\" & strClientNum & "_" & strInvNum & ".pdf"
        PageSetupDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
        PageSetupDialog1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
        prtFrmInvoice.PrinterSettings = PageSetupDialog1.PrinterSettings
        If prtFrmInvoice.PrinterSettings.IsValid Then
            prtFrmInvoice.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
            prtFrmInvoice.PrintFileName = txtVarFile
            prtFrmInvoice.PrintAction = Printing.PrintAction.PrintToFile
            prtFrmInvoice.Print()
        End If
```

But this does not work, it tells me the file can not be found, but the file is there
Exception is thrown at this line: eMail.From = New MailAddress(txtVarEmail)

```
'Send copy of Invoice per Email
        Try
            Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
            Dim eMail As New MailMessage()
            'Dim attachment As System.Net.Mail.Attachment
            LogFile.Refresh()
            SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = False
            SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(txtVarEmail, txtVarPasss)
            SmtpServer.Port = intVarPort
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
            SmtpServer.Host = txtVarSMTP
            eMail = New MailMessage()
            eMail.From = New MailAddress(txtVarEmail)
            eMail.To.Add(strClientEmail)
            eMail.Subject = "AltHealth Invoice"
            eMail.Body = "Please find your latest invoice attached"
            'attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(txtVarFile)
            'eMail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
            eMail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(txtVarFile))

            SmtpServer.Send(eMail)
            MsgBox("The Invoice has been sent sucessfully via email - File: " & txtVarFile)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Send failure: " & ex.ToString())
        End Try
```

Comment: Is "txtVarEmail" a valid variable when you're creating the new email? It is named like it was a textbox, but also appears to be declared as a string variable during printing. Do you have option explicit switched on?

Comment: Is the second snippet run right after the first (since you're using the same variable)? If so, probably the pdf is not ready yet.

Comment: @Jimi Yes, and I know it has to do with that. But how do I solve it?

Comment: Subscribe to the `PrintDocument.EndPrint` event to call from there the second code block. The email part.

Comment: What @dr.null suggests is OK, but you have to verify that the file is ready anyway. A simple loop that tries to open a Stream using that file path should be enough. What kind of loop, what kind of *awaiter* and what kind of time-out to set depends on the Platform and on your specific requirements. Maybe a StopWatch + Thread.Sleep(), `await Task.Delay()` + StopWatch (or CancellationToken), AutoResetEvent etc.